# Angular 2, Unable to validate form after populating it from firebase

Tags: forms, angular, validation, firebase

I have a EditAssignment form which I need to populate with the existing values in the database and then validate the form. First I retrieved the form values from firebase like this.

```
 this.assignment = this._db.object('/assignments-detail/' + asnDetailKey);
```

Then I stored the form values in a class variable (_assignment).

```
 this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => {
  this._assignment = asnDetails;
});
```

Then I populated the form using _assignment like this.

```
 <form [formGroup]="form">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subject">Assignment Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" formControlName="subject" [value]="_assignment?.subject">
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['subject'].touched && form.controls['subject'].hasError('required')">
      Please enter assignment subject.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="dueDate">Due Date</label>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" required="required" id="dueDate" formControlName="dueDate" [min]="today" [value]="_assignment?.dueDate">
   <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls['dueDate'].touched && form.controls['dueDate'].value==' | async'">
     Please enter a valid due date.
   </div>
  </div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onUpdate()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Edit Assignment</button>
 </form>
```

And finally I validate in typescript file using validate() method which i call from ngOnInit.

```
 validate() {
  this.form = this._fb.group({
  subject: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
  dueDate: ['']
});
```

I am successfully able to retrieve the values from database and populate the form but it is not validating. For example, When i click on Subject textbox and then click out, it is showing error message `please enter assignment subject` even though the textbox is not empty. Also the button is disabled.

[image: Image of my form]

Comment: You should populate your controls in your component, like this: `dueDate: ['someValue']`, not using value *attribute* in HTML. Also, the `required="required"` validation in HTML should go in component as well (`Validators.required`). And also note that you have a syntax error here (**==' | async'**): `...&& form.controls['dueDate'].value==' | async'">`

Comment: but how do I dynamically populate form controls inside the component ?

Comment: Call the function in your subscribe: `this.validate(asnDetails);` and in vaidate: `validate(data) { // fill form with the data values }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommend for using `templete-driven form` and `model-driven form` at the same time.

For **ReactiveForm**, you should initialize elements by

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
  subject: ['init value', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],   // init here
  ...
});
```

and for your situation(change value of subject), you shouldn't use `[value]`(which is for template-driven form), use `patchValue` instead.

```
this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => {
  this._assignment = asnDetails;
  if (this._assignment.subject) {
    this.form.get('subject').patchValue(this._assignment.subject);
  }
});
```

Comment: Validation working fine now. Thank you so much Pengyy :)

Comment: There seems to be a problem here. The code seems to be working fine when i visit the link first time, but after that if i visit other link and come back then it does not patch the values to form controls.

Comment: @PR7 it should work all the time. make sure `patchValue` has been executed every time.

Comment: setInputValues() {
    this.assignment.subscribe(asnDetails => {
    this._assignment = asnDetails;
    this.form.get('course').patchValue(this._assignment.course);
    this.form.get('batch').patchValue(this._assignment.batch);
    this.form.get('subject').patchValue(this._assignment.subject);
    this.form.get('name').patchValue(this._assignment.AsnName);
    this.form.get('description').patchValue(this._assignment.AsnDesc);
    this.form.get('dueDate').patchValue(this._assignment.dueDate);
    this.batches = this._db.list('/batches/' + this._assignment.course);
    });
    }

Comment: thats how im doing it, i also console.log the this._assignment and it showing all values but below statements are not patching values to form control

Answer (score 0):

```
    ngOnInit() {
          this.form = this._fb.group({
          subject:['', [Validators.required]],
          dueDate: [''] 
        }
```

otherwise, u should trigger the function inside ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
               validate();
            }
```

Comment: yes, thats how I did it. I Didnt post the entire code because it would make the post very large.

Comment: ok. i hope .this link helps to u...https://plnkr.co/edit/nzO0OtDltR6IIJAVXUE2?p=preview